# Reading numbers from a file using map

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to read a list of IDs (as integers) from a file in Python3. The file has a single ID per line and no blank lines.

```
with open(file_eval_id) as f:
    eval_ids = [list(map(int, line.split()))[0] for line in f]
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing it? I have doubts about referencing the `list(...)[0]` as the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
with open(file_eval_id) as f:
    eval_ids = [int(line) for line in f]
```

The code assumes, that ID is the only thing in the line.

Comment: You probably don't even need to `.strip()`.

Comment: Since there is only one ID per line, there is no need to use the `.strip()`

Comment: Yes, true. `int` will discard the end of line.